# IFRAME resize across subdomain on .Net platform

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, iframe

It's not any of the possible duplicates present on stackoverflow. Here is the problem statement.
I've two application running on two different subdomains.

**http://abc.myclient.net:1234/MyApplicationSite**: This is a Sharepoint site which is the hosting environment. My user control is deployed on this environment on the master page. The user control has a div element with an iframe. The src of iframe is set to the ASP.Net Web application of different subdomain discussed later. I'm using jquery-UI library to open up the div containing iFrame as a dialog popup. Let's call this sharepoint site as `consumer` henceforth.

**http://xyz.pqr.myclient.net:8080/MyApp/MyPage.aspx**: This is an ASP.Net Web Application on .Net platform 3.5. It serves as content inside iframe explained earlier. Let's call this `provider` henceforth. It contains an accordion control from jQuery-UI. On click of accordion head `activate` event is fired normally and I execute a javascript function to resize parent iFrame. On same domain I achieved this by calling `window.parent` DOM elements and then resized iFrame height from this web application. But I get `Permission denied` error now when consumer and provider resides on two different subdomains. I understand that this is due to the `Same Origin Policy`.

To fix this I just wanted to transfer the height value of web application to the host Sharepoint page. An event from from web application is fired - `accordionactivate` which I need to listen on the Sharepoint page javascript using `window.addEventListener` or `window.attachEvent` whichever is applicable. Since, Iframe is part of Sharepoint page and we have the new height value, so we can resize it after listening to the event raised from content window. To implement this, I used the following approaches but haven't succeeded so far.

- document.domain
- window.postMessage()
- easyXDM
- polling

The problem I face is that the event is not listened at the consumer end (SP site) and hence iFrame resize is not triggered. Let me know if any body have faced similar issues. I need a neat and clean cross - browser solution for this. Multiple approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we need is correct usage and understanding of postMessage and jQuery. First on provider i.e. on ASP.Net Web Application, inside my accordion js code, I call postSize method.

```
$(".my-accrdion-class").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        postSize();
    }
});
```

Then I define postSize like this.

```
    function postSize() {
       var height = jQuery(iFrameContentSelector).height();
       data = { 'height': height };
       window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data),"*");
    }
```

You will need to include the JSON2 library. Here, if you have only one consumer then instead of * give proper URL with port number and protocol too. In our case I apply a check on consumer end for the origin and the data passed is non - sensitive. So, no security concerns at this point.

Now on consumer end, i.e. inside the javascript for user control. Add the following code.

```
    // Here "addEventListener" is for standards-compliant web browsers and    "attachEvent" is for IE Browsers.
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    // Listen to message from child IFrame window
    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
    if (e.origin == 'http://xyz.pqr.myclient.net:8080') {
      var window_height = JSON.parse(e.data);
      var frame = $("#iFrameDiv iframe");
      frame.height(window_height.height);
      }
    }, false);
```

That's it. Here iFrameDiv contains my iFrame which is a server control.

The same discussion can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/706094/How-do-I-resize-iframe-across-subdomain-on-Net-pla)

Cheers,
Naman

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set up a reverse proxy server (using Apache) that pulled pages from multiple domains into (what appeared to the client) as a single domain and then I could easily reach across the IFrame border. The way this works, your end users get a single domain name for the proxy server. when you code the IFrame, use the proxy server address which will be routed back to MyApp. See this page for info on reverse proxy: [Apache Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC11/configure-apache-httpd-as-a-reverse-proxy-modproxy.html)
only in your case, add this to the httpd.conf file:

```
ProxyPass / http://abc.myclient.net:1234/MyApplicationSite
ProxyPass /MyApp http://xyz.pqr.myclient.net:8080/MyApp/MyPage.aspx
ProxyPassReverse /MyApp http://xyz.pqr.myclient.net:8080/MyApp/MyPage.aspx
```

Comment: Looks like an interesting technique, but can't comment anything before I test it. Unfortunately, Apache server configuration are not available on our client machine, so we are stuck with IIS. However, I resolved it using window.postmessage. See my answer. Cheers.

Comment: set up another stand-alone server to host the Apache - do not put it on the same system as IIS